# Cakephp find OR condition not working

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I am looking to display coupons that haven't expired yet and coupons that do not expire at all.  Here is my cakephp code:

```
public function coupons() {

$this->paginate['Coupon']=array(
    'limit'=>9,
    'order'=>'RAND()',
    'OR'=>array(
            'expires' =>0,
            'Coupon.end_date >'=>date('Y-m-d')
            )
    );
$c=$this->paginate('Coupon');
$this->set('allcoupons', $c);

}
```

Everything works correctly EXCEPT for coupons that have expired.  They still show up in my results.  I have a test record that expires before today, yet it still shows up in my results.  Is my 'OR' condition written incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

never mind.  I figured it out.  You have to encapsulate the 'or' behind 'conditions', like so:

```
public function coupons() {

$this->paginate['Coupon']=array(
    'limit'=>9,
    'order'=>'RAND()',
    'conditions'=>array(
            'OR'=>array(
                'expires' =>0,
                'Coupon.end_date >'=>date('Y-m-d')
            ))
    );
$c=$this->paginate('Coupon');
$this->set('allcoupons', $c);

}
```